# How to check Apple Pay and Google Pay availability in Flutter

Tags: flutter, applepay, google-pay

I need to list all available payment methods in my app, so in case Apple Pay is configured I need to show it in my payment methods list, and same for Google Pay.

Is there a way to check whether the user have Apple Pay / Google Pay configured on their device or still not yet configured?

I saw [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/pay)(pay) but it looks like it doesn't have that feature, any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to do it, so i'm sharing the answer..

Actually i could do it using [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) which is also supported by [google.dev](https://pub.dev/publishers/google.dev/packages)

1. Add the library first `pay: ^1.1.0` to your `pubspecs.yaml` 's dependencies.
2. Add the config file, new dart file call it `defaultConfigPayJson.dart` and paste inside it the code below, and sure you need to replace your merchant IDs and some other stuff:

   ```
   const String defaultApplePay = '''{
     "provider": "apple_pay",
     "data": {
       "merchantIdentifier": "merchant.com.domain.project",
       "displayName": "App name",
       "merchantCapabilities": ["3DS", "debit", "credit"],
       "supportedNetworks": ["amex", "visa", "discover", "masterCard"],
       "countryCode": "QA",
       "currencyCode": "QAR",
       "requiredBillingContactFields": [],
       "requiredShippingContactFields": [],
       "shippingMethods": []
     }
   }''';

   const String defaultGooglePay = '''{
     "provider": "google_pay",
     "data": {
       "environment": "TEST",
       "apiVersion": 2,
       "apiVersionMinor": 0,
       "allowedPaymentMethods": [{
         "type": "CARD",
         "tokenizationSpecification": {
           "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
           "parameters": {
             "gateway": "example",
             "gatewayMerchantId": "gatewayMerchantId"
           }
         },
         "parameters": {
           "allowedCardNetworks": ["VISA", "MASTERCARD"],
           "allowedAuthMethods": ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],
           "billingAddressRequired": true,
           "billingAddressParameters": {
             "format": "FULL",
             "phoneNumberRequired": true
           }
         }
       }],
       "merchantInfo": {
         "merchantId": "01234567890123456789",
         "merchantName": "Example Merchant Name"
       },
       "transactionInfo": {
         "countryCode": "QA",
         "currencyCode": "QAR"
       }
     }
   }''';
   ```
3. Add this code to your target page (where it is supposed to check the availability):

   ```
   import 'defaultConfigPayJson.dart' as payment_configurations;
   ...
   Pay _payClient;
   bool _hasApplePay = false;
   bool _hasGooglePay = false;
   ...
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();

     _payClient = Pay({
       PayProvider.google_pay: PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
           payment_configurations.defaultGooglePay),
       PayProvider.apple_pay: PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
           payment_configurations.defaultApplePay),
     });

     _checkIfGooglePayInstalled();
     _checkIfApplePayInstalled();
   }
   ```
4. Add finally call the availability check like this from wherever you need:

   ```
   Future <void> _checkIfApplePayInstalled() async {
     _hasApplePay = await _payClient.userCanPay(PayProvider.apple_pay);

     if (_hasApplePay) {
       setState(() {
         // Write here your code..
       });
       print('Apple Pay is available on this device!');
     } else {
       print('Apple Pay is not available on this device!');
     }
   }

   Future<void> _checkIfGooglePayInstalled() async {
     _hasGooglePay = await _payClient.userCanPay(PayProvider.google_pay);
     if (_hasGooglePay) {
       setState(() {
         // Write here your code..
       });
       print('Google Pay is available on this device!');
     } else {
       print('Google Pay is not available on this device!');
     }
   }
   ```