# How to implement recurrent payment in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase, payment

In ecommerce application, we have 1000+ products. **And we want to do recurrent payments like daily, weekly (multiple days can be selected), monthly etc for any product. How can we do that in flutter (Android & iOS).**

I check in app purchase. But the problem is that, we need to define the details regarding payment first on app store and play store. IN reality we are defining the payment on run time depending on the products buyer had choosen for deliveries.

Can anyone suggest a workflow/solution regarding this usecases.

Comment: are your products physical or digital?

Comment: @SujanGainju It is a B2B ecommerce application. The products are physical like eatables (food, beverages etc) listed on  mobile application

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment reply, you deal with the physical service. In that case, you do not need to use the Apple in-app purchase. The in-app purchase is only necessary if the app is used for digital goods.

For physical goods, you can use [apple pay](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) or [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) packages. [Flutter stripe doc](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay) shows its added functionality for apple pay.

[Apple Pay vs Apple In-App Purchase](https://medium.com/@mobomo/in-app-vs-apple-pay-bec9208cac8d#:%7E:text=In%20other%20words%2C%20you%20can,simple%20touch%20of%20an%20app.&text=In%2DApp%3A%20sells%20virtual%20goods,and%20subscriptions%20for%20digital%20content.&text=Apple%20Pay%3A%20sells%20physical%20goods,groceries%2C%20clothing%2C%20and%20appliances.)

[Check apple pay availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75593865/how-to-check-apple-pay-and-google-pay-availability-in-flutter)